# Invalid auth state parameter for google auth

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm using the Yii 2 authclient extension with [yii2-usuario](https://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), When i try to login to google, i'm redirected to

`https://localhost/yii2/frontend/web/index.php?r=user%2Fsecurity%2Fauth&authclient=google&state=a210c7124891a0083463a&code=4%2F0AX4XfWgAhMrw6CVtm4cj8-&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&prompt=none`

i get a 400 `Invalid auth state parameter.` error

```
yii\web\HttpException: Invalid auth state parameter. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-authclient\src\OAuth2.php:122
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-authclient\src\AuthAction.php(417): yii\authclient\OAuth2->fetchAccessToken('4/0AX4XfWgAhMrw...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-authclient\src\AuthAction.php(227): yii\authclient\AuthAction->authOAuth2(Object(Da\User\AuthClient\Google), Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-authclient\src\AuthAction.php(210): yii\authclient\AuthAction->auth(Object(Da\User\AuthClient\Google))
#3 [internal function]: yii\authclient\AuthAction->run()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Action.php(94): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(181): yii\base\Action->runWithParams(Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(534): yii\base\Controller->runAction('auth', Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(104): yii\base\Module->runAction('user/security/a...', Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(392): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\frontend\web\index.php(39): yii\base\Application->run()
#10 {main}
```

i'm also using `yii\web\DbSession`

when i change `yii\web\DbSession` to `yii\web\Session` it works. how do i get it working with `yii\web\DbSession`?

my session table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE `yiisession` (
  `id` char(40) NOT NULL,
  `expire` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` longblob NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

and in my `main.php`

```
 'session' => [
             'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession', 
            'sessionTable' => 'yiisession',
]
```

**Additional info**

| Info | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Yii version | 2.0.42.1 |
| Yii Auth Client version | 2.2 |
| PHP version | 8.0.8 |

**UPDATE**

my DB connection

```
'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
CREATE TABLE `session` (
  `id` char(40) NOT NULL,
  `expire` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` longblob DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Are the Id's supposed to be the same? I get this when i go to my contact page. when i submit the contact form the flash doesn't appear.

[image]

Comment: Try temporary to disable 'validateAuthState' => false for auth client and let us about the result

Comment: i think the problem is the session, sessions doesn;t work when i use `DbSession` not even the normal login works.

Comment: @dMd updated question with my db connection code, which works as i can read and write to db

Comment: @dMd you don't need to do that if you want use default `db` component, because that's the default value in `DbSession`.

Comment: How did you create your session table? Have you used the yii's migration to create it? The migration is supposed to create `id` column as `VARCHAR(256)` but yours `id` column is `CHAR(40)`.

Comment: @MichalHynčica there is no migration for db session table, read the doc https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-dbsession#$sessionTable-detail

Comment: @da-hype have u tried to switch back to default sessions?

Comment: @da-hype small note, according the doc fields `expire` and `data` are nullable and `Note that according to the php.ini setting of session.hash_function, you may need to adjust the length of the id column. For example, if session.hash_function=sha256, you should use length 64 instead of 40.`

Comment: i tried changing table name to `session` and i changed `id` length to 40. Still not working. Updated Question under `Update 2`

Comment: @SiZE Bah, deleted my table and went to https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-dbsession#$sessionTable-detail and copied the `create` table code and now it works!

Comment: @SiZE no migration? So, what do you think is this https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/migrations/m160313_153426_session_init.php ?

Comment: after testing the site, everything seems to work, except for the social login. im getting `Invalid auth state parameter` again

Comment: Did you try to dump/echo the state values that are compared? To check if they are different or if one is completely empty.